# Smoothing with Kalman filter

Tags: python, kalman-filter, pykalman

I'm testing Kalman library and not sure how to tweak to smooth filter:
Tracking a sinusoidal movement I get state measurements including errors because of noisy measurements.
Please look at Tracking image.[Track](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5noYL.png)
In Blue, the original track.
In Green, the track incl. errors in location calculation ( Used Least Square Fitting to find minimal error)
in Red, I'm testing pykalman filtering to smooth the track.

the current state

Running kf.filter I get very close tracking without smoothing. Why is the filter getting so close to state? How can I change the window time?

```
kf = KalmanFilter(transition_matrices = F, observation_matrices =H, transition_covariance=Q )
(filtered_state_means, filtered_state_covariances) = kf.filter(track_smooth)
```

F (9,9) matrix includes position, velocity and acceleration for 3 axes

```
F=np.array([
[1,1,.5,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,1,.5,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0],
```

H is an np.eye,  and Q is an np.eye(9)*4, the variance of states x,y,z

Comment: Hi @Guido, could you please provide the complete python code used to produce that example plot. I recently answered a question on using the `pykalman` library [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43377626/how-to-use-kalman-filter-in-python-for-location-data/43568887). To get more smoothing you probably want to increase the measurement co-variance (see example in answer to that question for increasing the ammount of smoothing).