# Kalman filter to predict previous step from future

Tags: python-3.x, kalman-filter, pykalman

I am new to Kalman filters and trying to use it for predicting missing values as well as getting smoothed observation from GPS data (latitude and longitude).

I am using pykalman and my code block looks like this:

```
data = data[['Lat', 'Lon']]
measurements = np.asarray(data, dtype='float')
measurements_masked = np.ma.masked_invalid(measurements)

# initial state of the form  [x0, x0_dot, x1, x1_dot]
initial_state_mean = [
    measurements[0, 0],
    0,
    measurements[0, 1],
    0
]

initial_state_covariance = [[ 10, 0, 0, 0], 
                            [  0, 1, 0, 0],
                            [  0, 0, 1, 0],
                            [  0, 0, 0, 1]]

# transition matrix to estimate new position given old position
transition_matrix = [
    [1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 1]
]

observation_matrix = [
    [1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0]
]

kf = KalmanFilter(
    transition_matrices=transition_matrix,
    observation_matrices=observation_matrix,
    initial_state_mean=initial_state_mean,
)

filtered_state_means = np.zeros((len(measurements), 4))
filtered_state_covariances = np.zeros((len(measurements), 4, 4))

for i in range(len(measurements)):
    if i == 0:
        filtered_state_means[i] = initial_state_mean
        filtered_state_covariances[i] = initial_state_covariance
    else:
        filtered_state_means[i], filtered_state_covariances[i] = (
        kf.filter_update(
            filtered_state_means[i-1],
            filtered_state_covariances[i-1],
            observation = measurements_masked[i])
        )
```

where data is a pandas dataframe from which latitude and longitude are extracted.

Is this logic correct? Also, what I want to do is to take observations which are closer to missing observation to predict missing values. For example, if, in an array of 10 samples, if 5th, 6th and 7th observations are missing, it makes more sense to predict 5th using 4th sample, predict 7th using 8th sample and predict 6th by taking an average of both 5th and 7th.

Does this approach make sense? If yes, how to do it using pykalman? If not, what can be done to predict missing values more accurately where a lot of consecutive values in an array are absent?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for a [fixed-interval smoother](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Fixed-interval_smoothers)? Per [this paper by Wall, Willsky and Sandell](http://sensorweb.lids.mit.edu/group/willsky/publ_pdfs/32_pub_STO.pdf), "smoothing refers to estimating a state vector at a point in time intermediate to a span of measurements." And there is an element of non-causality here since some of the measurements occur in the future. This would be a retrospective approach to estimating state.

Comment: pykalman implements a [smoothing method](https://pykalman.github.io/): `(smoothed_state_means, smoothed_state_covariances) = kf.smooth(measurements)`.

Comment: Missing observations as in predicting missing values where GPS signal is lost. I have GPS data which is updated every second as long as a person is driving. But whenever GPS signal is lost, the oberservations (latitude and longitude) of that second is missing. I wante to predict those missing values and I read everywhere that Kalman filter is the best option to do that. I will have a look at your article too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a kalman filter is a great fit for what you want. Below is an example with some dummy data where I've masked (hidden) some samples/measurements from the filter. As you can see the KF does a good job of reconstructing the 3 points missing from the middle. The KF will take care of the fact that observations nearer a particular time-stamp are most relevant for estimating that time-stamp (through the assumed dynamics).

This is slightly optimistic as the input data perfectly matches the assumption made in the KF (that  objects move with constant velocity). Note that the KF should also work well when velocity is actually changing. I've posted a previous longer answer on `pykalman` library here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43568887/4988601, which might help in understanding how KF work.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pykalman import KalmanFilter

# Some dummy values, assume we're heading in straightline
# at constant speed
lat_ideal = np.array(range(10))
lon_ideal = np.array(lat_ideal*3.5 + 10)

lat = lat_ideal + np.random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5, 10)
lon = lon_ideal + np.random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5, 10)

# Assing some indexes as missing
measurementMissingIdx = [False, False, False, False, True, True, True, False, False, False]

# Create the starte measurement matrix and mark some of the time-steps
# (rows) as missing (masked)
measurements = np.ma.asarray([lat, lon]).transpose()
measurements[measurementMissingIdx] = np.ma.masked

# Kalman filter settings:
# state vector is [lat, lat_dot, lon, lon_dot]
Transition_Matrix=[[1,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,1]]
Observation_Matrix=[[1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0]]

initial_state_mean = [measurements[0, 0], 0,
                      measurements[0, 1], 0]

kf=KalmanFilter(transition_matrices=Transition_Matrix,
            observation_matrices =Observation_Matrix,
            em_vars=['initial_state_covariance', 'initial_state_mean'
                     'transition_covariance', 'observation_covariance'])

kf.em(measurements, n_iter=5)

# Increase observation co-variance
kf.observation_covariance = kf.observation_covariance*10

(smoothed_state_means, smoothed_state_covariances) = kf.smooth(measurements)

plt.plot(lat_ideal,lon_ideal,'sb', label='ideal values', markerfacecolor='none')
plt.plot(measurements[:,0],measurements[:,1],'og',label='input measurements', markerfacecolor='none')
plt.plot(smoothed_state_means[:,0],smoothed_state_means[:,2],'xr',label='kalman output')

plt.xlabel("Latitude")
plt.ylabel("Longitude")
legend = plt.legend(loc=2)
plt.title("Constant Velocity Kalman Filter")
plt.show()
```

Which produces the graph below:

[image: Output of Kalman Filter]