# Filtering Magnetometer Heading with Kalman Filter

Tags: python, python-3.x, kalman-filter, magnetometer, pykalman

I am getting the magnetometer x and y magnitudes from my IMU sensor, and using these I am getting a heading by taking atan2(my, mx). However, I would like to implement a kalman filter in order to filter the heading. I was wondering what the parameters I would use would be? I am new to filtering. I would like to do this in python, if possible.

Comment: What have you tried? I've written a reasonably comprehensive answer on KF which will be relevant to your problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43568887/4988601 in your case I would suggest treating heading as your state variable assume its rate-of-change varies only slowly (as in the linked example).

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look and try to understand what you have. I have not tried any filtering, as I am not really sure where to start yet.